# How to execute Openstack CLIs using python subprocess.Popen (,,,env parameter)

Tags: python, openstack, openstack-keystone

I have one function run_cmd using

```
p = subprocess.Popen( cmd, shell = True, stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.PIPE, cwd = scriptdir, env = myenv )
```

when I call run_cmd from main

```
run_cmd(cli,"on", haltOnError="on")
```

I don't know how to use env - myenv parameter from subprocess.Popen.  As you are all know that, to run openstack CLI we must source to keystone_rc file where OS_ENV is from here.

```
export OS_USERNAME=admin
export OS_TENANT_NAME=admin
export NOVA_VERSION=1.1
export OS_PROJECT_NAME=admin
export OS_PASSWORD=xxxx_yyyy
export COMPUTE_API_VERSION=1.1
export no_proxy=,10.xxx.xxx.164,172.31.255.9
export OS_CLOUDNAME=overcloud
export OS_AUTH_URL=https://10.xxx.xxx.164:13000/v2.0
```

I have an alternate way to overcome my problem but I have to inject "source keystone_rc; openstack server list". If I can use env parameter from subprocess, that would be great. Any idea, I appreciate!.

Comment: You can deploy using Heat Template. why you want to use python script.

Comment: Create one dictionary and add all the environment variables in that dictionary and assign dictionary to parameter env in `subprocess` module